# Spring Boot - set location of application.properties in war file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a war file that knows to look in a specific path for a spring boot application.properties. For example, when running in a linux environment,

I'd like my maven build to some how build that app so that it knows to look at the following location:

```
/etc/projects/application.properties
```

To be clear, I want to avoid setting system or command line properties. I want to wire into spring the location of the file and have application server and os be unaware of how spring does that.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass  `-Dspring.config.location=/etc/projects/application.properties` as part of the `JAVA_OPTS` to Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

//edit:

I was sure that above will work, but..:)

according to documentation ([here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)) you can create `config` directory next to your war/jar file, and create `application.properties` file there. It will be loaded.
Ive tested that by cloning [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot) repo. Edit `HelloController` class in `initial` project:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

@Value("${test.property}")
private String testProperty;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot! Test property value="+testProperty;
}
}
```

build jar with maven:

```
mvn clean package
```

create `config` directory, add our property there, run app:

```
cd target
mkdir config
echo "test.property=Value from external config" >> config/application.properties 
java -jar gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
```

goto `localhost:8080` - value from external property file should be there :)

Ofcourse if you really have to store your files on `/etc/projects/` then you can create symlinks inside `config` dir.

Comment: That sounds promising, but it doesn't work. I've also tried file:// in front of the location and still no luck. The documents seem to suggest that spring.config.location is a system property but not a property configurable in the application.properties file.

Comment: look at edit. Sorry for confusion, I was sure it will be working before :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved my case.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class)
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/etc/projects/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = FlywayAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

Its not easily build time configurable, so if the properties file moves I have to change code. But in my case, that's unlikely so this is an acceptable solution.